Weyl chamber of $\mathfrak{so}(2,3)$?
The Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g} =  \mathfrak{so}(2,3)$ consists of $5 \times 5$ matrices $M$ satisfying
$$M^tB + BM=0$$
where $$B= \begin{pmatrix}  &  &  &  & 1 \\  &  &  & 1 &  \\  &  & 1 &  &  \\  & 1 &  &  &  \\ 1 &  &  &  &  \end{pmatrix}$$
I have proved that $$\mathfrak{a} = \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} \lambda_1 &  &  &  & \\  &  \lambda_2 &  &  &  \\  &  & 0 &  &  \\  &  &  &  -\lambda_2 &  \\  &  &  &  & -\lambda_1 \end{pmatrix} \mid \lambda_i \in \mathbb R\right\}$$ is a Cartan subalgebra. Hence dimension of $\mathfrak{a}$ is $2$.
Now let $(\varepsilon_1, \varepsilon_2)$ be the standard basis for $\mathfrak{a}^*$, which means that
$$\left\langle \epsilon_i, \begin{pmatrix} \lambda_1 &  &  &  & \\  &  \lambda_2 &  &  &  \\  &  & 0 &  &  \\  &  &  &  -\lambda_2 &  \\  &  &  &  & -\lambda_1 \end{pmatrix} \right\rangle = \lambda_i,$$
for $i = 1,2$ and $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle: \mathfrak{a}^{*} \times \mathfrak{a} \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is the natural pairing.
Let the   restricted root system is   $$\Sigma := \{\pm \varepsilon_1, \pm \varepsilon_2\} \cup \{\pm \varepsilon_i \mid i = 1,2\}.$$ A simple system $\Delta \subset \Sigma$ is given by $$\Delta: = \{\alpha_1 := \varepsilon_1 - \varepsilon_2, \alpha_2= \varepsilon_2\}$$
Let $\overline{\mathfrak{a}}^+$  be the closed positive Weyl chamber of $\mathfrak{a}$ associated with $\Delta$, which is defined by $$\{Y\in \mathfrak{a} \mid \langle \alpha, Y\rangle \geq 0 \ \forall \alpha \in \Delta\}.$$
$\textbf{Questions:}$
Is  $$\overline{\mathfrak{a}}^+ = \left\{\begin{pmatrix} e^a &  &  &  & \\  &  e^b &  &  &  \\  &  & 0 &  &  \\  &  &  &  e^{-b} &  \\  &  &  &  & e^{-a} \end{pmatrix} \mid a \geq b \geq 0\right\}?$$
We definite the Cartan decomposition as follows:  Any element $g \in G$ can be written as a product
$$g = k \text{exp}(\mu(g))l$$ with $k, l \in K$ and $\mu(g) \in \overline{\mathfrak{a}}^+$, and $\mu (g)$ is uniquely determined by $g$. The map $\mu: G \rightarrow \overline{\mathfrak{a}}^+$ is a continuous map called Cartan projection.
Can we take $$\mu(g) = \begin{pmatrix} e^{\mu (a)} &  &  &  & \\  &  e^{\mu(b)} &  &  &  \\  &  & 0 &  &  \\  &  &  &  e^{-\mu(b)} &  \\  &  &  &  & e^{-\mu (a)} \end{pmatrix}?$$
